# Null-terminated string, opening file for reading

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I'm experimenting with `sys_open` syscall and I get file descriptor for reading. Here is my program:

```
SYS_exit equ 0x3C

SYS_open equ 0x02
O_RDONLY equ 0x00
O_WRONLY equ 0x01
O_RDWR equ 0x02

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, SYS_open
    mov rdi, file_name
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY
    mov rdx, 0x00
    syscall

    mov eax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, 0x00

    syscall

section .data
    file_name: db '/path/to/test\0'
```

So when I ran `strace ./bin` I got the output:

```
open("/path/to/test\\0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
exit(0)
```

After deleting the null-terminal it seemed to work fine:

```
open("/path/to/test", O_RDONLY) = 3
exit(0)                                 = ?
```

I'm curious about how does the assembler knows the lenght of my string. The content of data section in the binary is this:

```
Contents of section .data:
 6000d8 2f706174 682f746f 2f746573 74        /path/to/test
```

I expected the string is read till reaching the null-terminator. How does it work?

Comment: It worked because the padding after your `db` is zero.  Nothing based on the string length is written into the output file, and it would break if you had any other data after it.

Comment: @PeterCordes But I did not use int `0x80`. Only `syscall`s.

Comment: derp, I must have been half asleep.  I think I saw the `0x00` or something on a line right after `SYS_exit`, and had a knee-jerk reaction without realizing it was a `mov`, and `00` not `80`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the way you defined the following data:

```
section .data
    file_name: db '/path/to/test\0'
```

The trailing `NUL` character is missing, since the `\0` inside the string corresponds to the characters `\` and `0`, it should be defined instead as:

```
section .data
    file_name: db '/path/to/test', 0
```

Comment: Nice answer. I was puzzled by the question and trusted the OP dump of the data section, when, in fact, it was missing the `\` and `0` chars. :)

Comment: NASM actually can translate the C-like meta strings like `\0`, but you have to enclose them in backticks. Not sure how to format that in SO comment, so I will try probably with several edits comming: `db \`\0\`` should define single zero byte in NASM. Check listing file (`-l` nasm option) to verify the machine code output after assembling. With quotes and apostrophe you have to be literal, and use the way from answer to define zero. https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2